# How to send money to any paypal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-soap

Is it possible to send money using paypal API to any paypal account (not just to API credentials owner). I know that it's possible to do that using IPN, but I need to use SOAP.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You've got two main options: use the [MassPay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/) or [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).

> **Note**: Adaptive Payments is not available for new integrations.
>   PayPal provides documentation to only support existing integrations

The Adaptive Payments option gives you a lot more control over the payment <del>and is the future direction of the Paypal APIs</del>.  It supports SOAP, NVP, JSON and plain XML.   MassPay has both a SOAP and NVP interface.

IPNs are a totally different subject: https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Comment: many thanks! Adaptive Payments API looks to be the right option for me

Comment: I am looking into Adaptive Payments, but it seems that all it talks about is recieving money, while I want to send out from my account to another.

Comment: @hakurin Adaptive payments will work if you are ok with the sender manually approving the transaction through Paypal's interface. If you need to send API-request-driven payments (i.e. scheduled transfers), you want the MassPay API.

In case this helps anyone else, the analogue for receiving funds w/o user interaction (/charging credit cards) is the Direct Pay feature of the Payment Pro product.

Comment: Adaptive Payments allows you to make disbursements (outgoing payments) as well. You can also choose who pays the Paypal fees (you, or the receiver of the funds). There are much more complicated situations possible with Adaptive Payments as well. For example, you can automatically split payments between multiple recipients.

Comment: Hi. I have similar task. Can I using only Express Checkount for it or mandatory Adaptive Payments / MassPay?

Comment: PayPal's Adaptive Payments Intro leads off with this deprecation notce: "Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal." So what's the modern alternative?

Comment: Any advise here on what's the best?

Comment: Both methods listed in this answer are deprecated. I think the alternative to them is PayPal Payouts.

Comment: ATM I can't find any option to send money to someone using API. This accepted answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 15):

Seems like lot of things are now deprecated. You should use [PayPal Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/).

Use PayPal Payouts to send money to multiple people at the same time.

To send a payout, you need to know:

1. Each recipient's email address, a domestic mobile number, or payer ID (an encrypted PayPal account number)
2. Payment amount (per recipient)
3. Currency code (one currency per payout)

Comment: is it possible to do a transfer from a paypal account to another one programmatically ? and using what paypal api?

Comment: When I click on PayPal Payout it takes me to help centre so not sure if this is still working or it's gone too??

Comment: @user666 did you find an answer to your question ?

Comment: @George Not yet