# How can I do the reverse of a regular PayPal transaction? (Pay out to the customer rather than them paying us)

Tags: asp.net, post, transactions, paypal, dotnetnuke

How can I do the reverse of a regular PayPal transaction. The only information I found in their documents was for the customer to pay us for things. What if we want to pay out the customer?

Is there a way to give a transaction type to reverse and pay out to the customer instead of them paying us?

**Update: Turns out you can use Mass Payments to pay out to customers... just needed to look on StackOverflow a bit more ([[How to send money to any paypal account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559808/paypal-api-send-money-to-any-paypal-account)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559808/paypal-api-send-money-to-any-paypal-account)). My apologies.**

Comment: Is this related to software development?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build a form that allows my customers to do a cash out. Posting the transaction to Paypal is part of building that form. Thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you just used the customer's paypal account as the destination address?  That would send them the money, but they would end up paying the paypal transaction fees.

Comment: That might work... I'm not worried about the paypal transaction fees, we can add in more money to cover that. How would we log in with our paypal account to complete the transaction if we're not there though?