# Paypal integration with PHP

Tags: php, api, paypal

Hai,

I need a system that automatically transfer funds from one paypal account to another paypal account when i click on a button. Is there any paypal API with PHP to perform this task.

thanks

Answer (score 10):

This is not actually that easy to Google because the Paypal API documentation is a mess. There are several different ways to do almost everything, and it seems like Paypal's expectation is that you memorize the brand names they have for services with the core functionality of those services.

A pain.

But there is already a good answer for this question here on stackoverflow.com

[How to send money to any paypal account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559808/paypal-api-send-money-to-any-paypal-account)

Comment: Very helpful, gentle and kind answer. :)