# How do I transfer money from one account to the other using PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need to transfer money form an accountant to some employees using PayPal, from within an internal application. On PayPal website it is specified that a transfer of money is free(inside USA) or that the fee is smaller than for payments (outside USA).

The scenario is:

1. login as accountant in the internal application
2. click a button: pay employee
3. if the accountant is not logged into PayPal, he should be redirected to the PayPal page and login
4. only after the accountant has logged in, he can do the money transfer
5. the accountant goes to PayPal and approves the money transfers

I saw the options of using Classic API or Rest API.However, I did't find a call for "transfer money" I have found only "create payment" options and succeeded in implementing the "pay"  call using Classic API credentials.

So, how do I transfer money from one account to the other using PayPal. What it's better to use: Rest API or Classic API? How exactly to I use any of the two opetions?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559808/paypal-api-send-money-to-any-paypal-account

Comment: I've seen that question. However, it doesn't answer my question about how to use 'transfer money' and not 'pay money'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you are looking for (based on your fee requirements) is "Personal Payments". You can implement Personal Payments using the classic API called "Adaptive Payments". All you need to do is set the PaymentType as "PERSONAL" if your payment use cases qualify as personal payments. You can find out how to use Adaptive Payments APIs here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint! I made two accounts in sandbox. I can transfer money from one account to the other. Another issue I'm seing here... the moneys are transferred right away if I provide the API USer Id and Password. I was expecting the condition that the user logs into paypal and approves the payment.  I'm not sure if this is different in sandbox than in the live environment.

Comment: what you are doing is called "implicit payments" -when the API Caller and the Sender are the same. So please create another buyer account in sandbox and use that as the sender. Then you can see the condition where the sender needs to login to PayPal to approve the payment.

Comment: Don't forget to set the senderEmail field in the PAY request to your own account (the one the API credentials came from) or it won't be considered an implicit payment. I spent a few hours on this, just thought I'd pass it on.