# I want to give user money using paypal

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on the application where after some process the user would get credit which they can later cash out.
I want user to cash out this money using pay-pal but don't know where to start for it. Does anyone done similar to this previously. Please provide ways to cashout using pay-pal or any other payment gateway.

Comment: [Adaptative payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) seems to be the right way to proceed. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send money to any paypal account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559808/how-to-send-money-to-any-paypal-account)

Answer (score 1):

Paypal has a simple API to do payments as a merchant. See the following URL: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/ht_MassPay-customPayouts/

> The Mass Pay API enables you to send up to 250 payouts with a single call. Identify the payees using their e-mail addresses, PayPal User IDs, or mobile phone numbers.

Comment: Can this be used in Android?

Answer (score 0):

**Stripe** has created a Java library for Android allowing you to easily submit payments from the platform.

You can try Stripe integration in your application , it might be help you. Its free API for payment gateway.

The money will then be **paid into their Stripe account** minus Stripe's fees and your own (if any).

See here for further info:

[Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect)

[Stripe Connect and paying my users](https://support.stripe.com/questions/stripe-connect-vs-sending-transfers-via-api)

[Sending Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers)

[Getting Paid](https://stripe.com/help/transfers)

[Send payouts with Stripe](https://stripe.com/blog/send-payouts-with-stripe)

Answer (score 0):

The Mass Pay API enables you to send up to 250 payouts with a single call. Identify the payees using their e-mail addresses, PayPal User IDs, or mobile phone numbers.

1.Set Up the Call and Authentication

Specify the endpoint, call name, API credentials, and the version of the API you're calling:

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp   # Sandbox endpoint  
USER=<Caller_ID>        # the PayPal User ID of the caller account  
PWD=<Caller_Pswd>       # the caller account Password  
SIGNATURE=<Caller_Sig>  # the caller account Signature  
METHOD=MassPay          # API operation  
VERSION=93              # API version
```

2.Set the Global Call Values

Set the RECEIVERTYPE and CURRENCYCODE values, and a customized EMAILSUBJECT (there can be only one of each of these values per call):

```
RECEIVERTYPE=EmailAddress                     # set to EmailAddress, UserID, or PhoneNumber  
CURRENCYCODE=USD                              # currency code for all payouts  
EMAILSUBJECT=You have a payment from TEST     # custom e-mail subject for all payouts
```

3.Set Up the Payouts

Specify the details for each payout. You can add a custom message and tracking number to each payout, as shown:

```
L_AMT0=1.23                                 # 1st txn amount, starting at "0"  
L_EMAIL0=e-mail_1@example.com               # e-dress of 1st payee  
L_NOTE0= Thank you for our catered lunch.   # custom e-mail msg for 1st payee  
L_UNIQUEID0=TxnNo123                        # unique ID for txn  

L_AMT1=4.56                                 # 2nd txn amount  
L_EMAIL1=e-mail_2@example.com  
L_NOTE1= Thank you the Balloons!  
L_UNIQUEID1=TxnNo456
```

4.Send the Request

The following cURL command shows a complete example of how to make three payouts using a single Mass Pay call:

```
curl -s --insecure https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp -d   
"USER=<Caller_ID>  
&PWD=<Caller_Pswd>  
&SIGNATURE=<Caller_Sig>  
&METHOD=MassPay  
&VERSION=93  
&RECEIVERTYPE=EmailAddress  
&CURRENCYCODE=USD  
&EMAILSUBJECT= You have a new payment from TEST  
&L_EMAIL0=e-mail_1@example.com  
&L_AMT0=1.23  
&L_NOTE0= Thank you for our catered lunch.  
&L_UNIQUEID0=TxnNo123  
&L_EMAIL1=e-mail_2@example.com  
&L_AMT1=4.56  
&L_NOTE1= Thank you for the Balloons!  
&L_UNIQUEID1=TxnNo456  
&L_EMAIL2=e-mail_3@example.com  
&L_AMT2=7.89  
&L_NOTE2= Thank you for your cleaning service.  
&L_UNIQUEID2=TxnNo789"
```