# How to transfer amount from one paypal account to another paypal account in android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I have followed below link for shopping payment using paypal and I successfully developed it.

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-integrating-paypal-using-php-mysql-part-1/

But now I need to transfer money from one paypal account to another paypal account.I searched on google I came across below link.

[How to send money to any paypal account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559808/how-to-send-money-to-any-paypal-account)

But now I don't know how to use Adaptive Payments API in android app?I do not have any source code regarding Adaptive Payments or any other way of transferring amount from one paypal account to another paypal account in android.

If anyone have any piece of code or solution for this,then please assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Current Mobile SDK https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/ , it doesn't support the Adaptive payment feature.

PayPal has an old MPL package which can support it. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/?mark=MPL , but it's deprecated and lack of support. But you can take a look.