# paypal automaically pay from my account to vendor account

Tags: java, paypal

Is there any way I can automatically transfer (Java API) money to vendor account from my paypal account?

Scenario:

1. Place a job in my application
2. Vendor accepts and perform job
3. My app will receive completion status
4. Release money to vendor

I need to automatically release money to vendor once job is completed. Is there any paypal API?

Comment: @downvoter, Could you explain?

Comment: Please review what is typically considered a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a [PayPal Java SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK) that you should look at.
If you have a specific question about achieving one of the four points in your scenario, then you should post a new question (along with the code you've written, error messages, etc, etc)

There's also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559808/how-to-send-money-to-any-paypal-account), which may have some some useful answers.

Comment: Thanks @Catchwa. I am already using this SDK for receiving money from customer. I couldn't find any samples for paying to vendor.

Comment: @Maheshkumar - added a link to a question that may help

Comment: thanks. Delayed Chained Payments in Adaptive Payments fits to my requirements. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/